# YouTube save position

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

Is there a way to autosave positions of YouTube videos? Preferably automatically and without plugins.

This worked a month ago without a plugin, now it does not work anymore (for me).

Ubuntu Linux and Chromium browser.

Comment: Still works for me, but with the stipulations in my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the built in YouTube video resume feature is only for videos "*longer than 20 minutes*". And, of course, you have to be logged in. There are also these stipulations: "*you've watched more than one minute of the video and there are more than three minutes left.*".

[Here's my source](https://youtube.googleblog.com/2009/09/release-notes-91709.html) from long ago when the feature was first released, where they state:

> **Resume where you left off**: Let's say you're watching an epic (read: longer than 20 minutes) video, and you get distracted and click
>   away. The next time you return to the video, it will resume where you
>   left off watching, assuming you've watched more than one minute of the
>   video and there are more than three minutes left.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it is not possible without an external plugin. You can try one such as [Video Resumer on Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-resumer/bongjkoajofkfpofginnhecihgaeldpe?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) and [resumeLater on Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/resumelater/)